# Maintaining state between touches in custom UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm implementing a custom `UIGestureRecognizer`, which does a few things including recognizing a double tap. I'm trying to keep track of whether it's a double tap by keeping track of the number of taps as a local variable of the custom gesture class.

Naturally, as the user initiates a double tap, they have to lift the finger in-between the taps, which causes `touchesEnded` to be called. However, this always seems to also trigger `reset()` to be called as well, which I've implemented to reset all my local state (as I should so the state is cleared when the recognizer has indeed properly ended). Due to this, I'm not able to keep track of whether there was a prior tap each time `touchesBegan` is called.

Is there a proper way to implement this? I guess I'm just curious how `UITapGestureRecognizer` is implementing multiple taps within one recognizer session.

Comment: Why don't you use separate `UIGestureRecognizer` for double taps events?

Comment: There's additional movement I have to keep track for the gesture to be considered "recognized" as a whole, so I can't just pull out the double-tap part as a separate recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I ended up using `reset()` to clear states normally but still kept track of the last touched session (a session that began with `touchesBegan` and finished with `touchesEnded`) in order to determine whether there was a previous tap at the beginning of each session.

Not sure if this is how a double tap is implemented with `UITapGestureRecognizer`, but would happy to hear other solutions if anyone knows of any.